# Equivalent finite sets have the same number of elements (odd proof)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am working through Rudin's POMA and in Chapter 2 on Basic Topology he gives the following definition of one-to-one correspondence:

> If there exists a 1-1 mapping of $A$ *onto* $B$, we say that $A$ and $B$ can be put in 1-1 *correspondence*, or that $A$ and $B$ have the same *cardinal number*, or, briefly, that $A$ and $B$ are *equivalent*, and we write $A\sim B$. This relation clearly has the following properties:
>
> - It is reflexive: $A\sim A$.
> - It is symmetric: If $A\sim B$, then $B\sim A$.
> - It is transitive: If $A\sim B$ and $B\sim C$, then $A\sim C$.

Rudin later goes on to say, "For two finite sets $A$ and $B$, we evidently have $A\sim B$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ contain the same number of elements."

Rudin never defines what cardinal or ordinal numbers are (even though he says $A\sim B$ for finite sets means $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinal number...he never defines a cardinal number) and does not go into set theory in any real depth.

---

**Curiosity:** I was thinking about Rudin's statement about finite sets and was wondering how one might prove that. I read an alleged proof in Raffi Grinberg's *Real Analysis Lifesaver* book (a book I really do not like to be honest), and I'm really questioning whether or not it is accurate. It is reproduced below:

> **Raffi's proof:** Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets. We claim that $A\sim B$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements.
>
> If $A\sim B$, then there exists a function that maps *every* element of $A$ (since $f$ is a well-defined function) to at most one element of $B$ (since $f$ is injective), and every element of $B$ is mapped to by some element of $A$ (since $f$ is surjective). So for every element of $A$ there is a corresponding element of $B$, and all elements of $B$ are covered by this correspondence, so $A$ and $B$ must have the same number of elements.
>
> If $A$ and $B$ have the same number $n$ of elements, then we can write the sets as $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$. Let $f\colon A\to B$ be defined as $f\colon a_i\mapsto b_i$, for every $1\leq i\leq n$. Then $f$ is a one-to-one, onto function, so $f$ is a bijection. We have found a bijection $A\to B$, so $A\sim B$.

**Question:** Is this proof really correct? It seems hand-wavy at best, especially the first part (the forward direction)---the finiteness of $A$ and $B$ do not seem to matter. The same argument would seem to work in the case of infinite sets $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$, where $\mathbb N\sim\mathbb Z$, but we do not think of these sets as having the same number of elements in the manner argued above (do we?). More concerning, since Grinberg admits in the introduction/preface that his book is basically based on Rudin's, I wonder how he proposes to prove something about cardinal numbers (i.e., that equivalent finite sets have the same cardinal number) when they have not actually been defined (in his book or in Rudin's).

I was reading in Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory* that, "Now it turns out that there is no way of defining $\operatorname{card} A$ that is really simple" (p. 136). He later gives the definition: "For any set $A$, define the *cardinal number* of $A$ ($\operatorname{card} A$) to be the least ordinal equinumerous to $A$" (p. 197).

Ultimately, there seems to be a fair amount going on here (to a novice like me at least), but I did not find Grinberg's proof very convincing. Am I wrong to feel that way? Is there an easy fix? Any thoughts?

Comment: I agree that it is a bit odd ... I always thought cardinality was defined to be an equivalence relation based on bijections, so this proof, in the context I learned, is meaningless. Do you happen to know what Grinberg's definition of number of elements is? I have a feeling that its a handwavy definition, which is probably why the proof is handwavy.

Comment: @RushabhMehta He never defines "number of elements"---[here](https://i.imgur.com/pJh08JV.png) he defines cardinality and [here](https://i.imgur.com/VLcAGRu.png) he states and "proves" the theorem. The proof really does not make much sense to me. It seems, as you said, "meaningless," but I'm no set-theorist...

Comment: Honestly, this is a excellent question, and I totally agree with you (trust me, I'm pretty harsh on new users so great job)! Enjoy your upvote.

Comment: Does he define "finiteness"?

Comment: @RushabhMehta Thanks--it's probably worth noting that Grinberg only graduated with honors from Princeton with a degree in math in 2012 (from back cover). It's not like he's a professor or anything. I don't want to question his ability, but some things in that book look very wrong. For example, [here](https://i.imgur.com/1yXy5Id.png) is his explanation/proof for why $\mathbb Z$ is countable. But his explanation is entirely deficient in my opinion.

Comment: @RushabhMehta [...] Well, maybe I'm being overly harsh in the sense that *he's not wrong*, but his "explanation" does not really provide any insight. I tried writing [something](https://i.imgur.com/BaMnHqS.png) up that details things more clearly. I don't know--I'm surprised Princeton University Press published that book, but what do I know...it has its uses in some places I suppose.

Comment: @Jessica I don't really see an issue with the proof that $\mathbb Z$ is countable. Sure, the argument that it is a bijection could be more rigorous, but I think that it's sufficiently detailed. But, the work you've done is great! Often, math proofs tend to make assumptions (i.e., Grinberg's assumption that the linearity of the function implies injectivity), but proving these things by hand is both a good exercise and solidifies your understanding.